# Using Pointers in to call array elements from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to write a code that moves and switches the first three elements of an array.  The main function gets array length and elements and then displays results of function call.  Function `roll` takes elements from array `a1`, moves the first three elements, and then stores them to array `a2`.  I must use pointer subscripts and cannot have `[]` in the function.  I must use this prototype:

`void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2)`

Here is the code I've written.  I must not be calling the function correctly, or the function does not assign the elements into array `a2` properly because I only get `0` is output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int *p, *q;
    q = a2;

    for(p = a1; p < a1 + n; p++)
            *p = *(p+2);
            *(p+1) = *p;
            *(p+2) = *(p+1);
            *q = *p;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, x;

    printf("Enter the length of the array:\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
    int a[x];
    int b[x];
    //      int new_arr[x];

    printf("Enter the elements of the array:\n");
            for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
                    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    roll(a, x, b);
    printf("The output array is:");
    //      for(i = 0; i < x; i++);
            printf("%d", *b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you assign `*p = *(p+2);` and then make `*(p+1) = *p;` and finally `*(p+2) = *(p+1);` -- what have you just assigned to `*(p+2)`?? (hint: take out a pencil and paper and write out the 1st 3 elements and track the logic through)

Comment: Ok, so I changed the logic to make sure that all of those are accounted for.  The problem I have is that the call to the function is not reading the function results.  At least that's what I think is happening.  The printf in the main function is returning meaningless numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you wanted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
int *p, *q;
q = a2;
p = a1;

        int temp=*p;
        *p = *(p+2);
        *(p+2)=*(p+1);
        *(p+1)=temp;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            *(a2+i)=*(p+i);

        }


}

int main(void)
{
int i, x;

printf("Enter the length of the array:\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
int a[x];
int b[x];
  //      int new_arr[x];
printf("Enter the elements of the array:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
               {
                   scanf("%d", &a[i]);
                    b[i]=a[i];
               }
roll(a, x, b);

  for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
        printf("%d\n", *(b+i));

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't compiled this, but:

```
for(p = a1; p < a1 + n; p++)
    *p = *(p+2);
    *(p+1) = *p;
    *(p+2) = *(p+1);
    *q = *p;
```

will only run the first line `*p = *(p+2)` through the `for ()` loop.

You need to put braces in there:

```
for(p = a1; p < a1 + n; p++)
{
    *p = *(p+2);
    *(p+1) = *p;
    *(p+2) = *(p+1);
    *q = *p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat unclear what you mean by:

> **Function 'roll' takes elements from array a1, moves the first three elements, and then stores them to array a2.**

A traditional **Roll** operation on an array will exchange the **n<sup>th</sup>** element with the first (the historic origin being a Roll of a value on a calculator stack to the current line). If that is the case, you can use a simple:

```
void roll (int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int tmp = *a1;          /* save the 1st element of a1 */

    *a2++ = *(a1++ + --n);  /* store the nth element of a1 as a2[0] */
    while (--n)             /* for the next n-2 elements */
        *a2++ = *a1++;      /* assign to a2 in order */
    *a2 = tmp;              /* assign the 1st of a1 as the nth of a2 */
}
```

You can index it any way you like, simply decrementing `'n'` is as simple a way as any. Saving the first element of `a1` as `tmp` allows you to increment the `a1` and `a2` directly (your `roll` function receives copies of the pointers).

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void roll (int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    int tmp = *a1;          /* save the 1st element of a1 */

    *a2++ = *(a1++ + --n);  /* store the nth element of a1 as a2[0] */
    while (--n)             /* for the next n-2 elements */
        *a2++ = *a1++;      /* assign to a2 in order */
    *a2 = tmp;              /* assign the 1st of a1 as the nth of a2 */
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, x;

    printf ("Enter the length of the array: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int a[x], b[x], *p = b;

    printf ("Enter the elements\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf ("  a[%2d]: ", i);
        if (scanf ("%d", &a[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        b[i] = a[i];    /* initialize b */
    }

    roll (a, x, b);

    printf("The output array is:");
    while (x--)
        printf (" %2d", *p++);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if your purpose is only to swap elements 1 & 3 from `a1` to `a2`, then `'n'` serves no purpose in the function other than to allow a check that `n > 2` to insure you don't attempt to access an array outside the bounds, but that in itself seems doubtful)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_roll
Enter the length of the array: 5
Enter the elements
  a[ 0]: 1
  a[ 1]: 2
  a[ 2]: 3
  a[ 3]: 4
  a[ 4]: 5
The output array is:  5  2  3  4  1
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Also, drop a line if what you mean by **Roll** is different than the traditional roll I have described.

If you did simply want to operate on the first 3 elements of `a1` in `a2` (note: `b` will then need to be fully initialized, as done above), you can simply use:

```
roll (a, 3, b);
```

**Example w/roll (a, 3, b)**

```
$ ./bin/array_roll
Enter the length of the array: 5
Enter the elements
  a[ 0]: 1
  a[ 1]: 2
  a[ 2]: 3
  a[ 3]: 4
  a[ 4]: 5
The output array is:  3  2  1  4  5
```

---

**Example Rolling Element 3 Down, Pushing Remainder Up**

After your comment defining **"roll"**, it just takes a tweak to change the current `roll` function to a `roll3` function that will roll the 3rd element in `a1` to the beginning of `a2` and then fill the remainder of `a2` with the remaining elements of `a1` in order. The twist here is rather than looping over `--n` it is not helpful to loop `for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)` so you can test for the rolled index and skip copying from `a1` to `a2`, e.g. (`if (i == 2) {/* skip */}`).

You can do something like:

```
void roll3 (int *a1, int n, int *a2)
{
    *a2++ = *(a1 + 2);      /* store the 3rd element of a1 as a2[0] */
    n--;                    /* decrement n (we have filled 1-element) */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, a2++) {  /* loop n-1 times, increment a2 */
        if (i == 2)         /* if we reach rolled index, increment a1 */
            a1++;
        *a2 = *a1++;        /* assign elements */
    }
}
```

Calling as:

```
    roll3 (a, x, b);
```

**Example with roll3 function**

```
$ ./bin/array_roll
Enter the length of the array: 5
Enter the elements
  a[ 0]: 1
  a[ 1]: 2
  a[ 2]: 3
  a[ 3]: 4
  a[ 4]: 5
The output array is:  3  1  2  4  5
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. By now, handling pointer increment/decrement and looping to fill should be starting to sink in. If not, the best way to learn is to take out a No. 2 Pencil and pieces of Paper, draw `a1` and `a2` and then step through the loop drawing lines as each element is assigned to see which element is going where -- and how.

Comment: The "roll" function is to roll the first three elements of the array.  So if the array elements are: {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}  after calling "roll" the results should be: {6, 2, 4, 8, 10}.  Does that make sense?  Notice the first three elements were incremented one index higher.  The catch is that I must use pointer arithmetic only in the function.  I can't use any array subscripting.  No use of "[]" is allowed within the function.

Comment: Ok, so you are just rolling the nth (3rd) element and pushing the rest up. Give me a bit and I'll drop another update.

Comment: OK, did you add the new function at the end of your question. Just edit your question and add a new block at the end.  (also you can make it a generic `rolln` and pass the element to roll -- **but** you must make sure `a2` is fully initialized before you call the function)

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that helped..I got it working...the problem was in my call..I had an extra ';' after the for loop that was stopping it from running...Thank you all so much!